# script to replace a string with some special characters in linux

Tags: sed

I want to replace the following line:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "patient")
```

with this line:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "patient", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
```

I prefer to use `sed` but I cannot make it work for me due to these special characters. Any body can help me?

Comment: If you add the [code you have tried so far](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) you help people answering your question.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed/29626460#29626460

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just that one line, you could say

```
sed 's/)$/, cascade = CascadeType.All)/'
```

to insert `, cascade = CascadeType.All)` before the closing regex (`$` matches the end of the line here).

I suspect, though, that you have a file in which there are more lines that should remain unchanged, and that you want the substitution to happen only in this line. In this event, you'll need some criterium that uniquely identifies the line -- most commonly a regex. If, for example, this is the only line that begins with `@OneToMany(`, you could use

```
sed '/^@OneToMany(/ s/)$/, cascade = CascadeType.All)/'
```

This will instruct `sed` to attempt the substitution only if the current line matches the regex `^@OneToMany(`. If there are other lines that begin this way and should remain untouched, find a regex that uniquely identifies the line and use it instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `awk` version:

```
awk '/@OneToMany/ {sub(/\)/,", cascade = CascadeType.ALL&")}1' file
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "patient", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
```